# Using Civi for a signposting service

Tags: civimail, civicase

I am trying to see if there is a way we can use Civi to help our signposting service.

Workers talk to a client about their lives and as a consequence may want to make a referral to a number of different agencies (max = 5 at one time)

Is there a way the worker could select a number of external organisations and with one click send a referral email with basic name/address information?

Thanks

Graham

Answer (score 2):

welcome to civi and SE.

There are a number of ways to address the requirements and partly would depend on your CMS.

For example with Drupal you can use Webform module (with civicrm integration) as a simple way of recording an interaction, then choosing the required 3rd party, pulling in their email and therefore sending an email, from Webform. The text of that email can be tweaked to provide whatever information needs to be passed on to them.

In pure civi this would be handled by creating an Activity and 'assigning' it to the 3rd Party, and this causes CiviCRM to fire off an email (assuming that setting is 'on' for your system) but you don't have much control, out of the box, as to what gets sent.

Comment: Actually the activity assignee email content is a message template you can edit, it just happens to be called "Cases - Send Copy of an Activity".

Comment: oh good to know. I also wondered if you could do this via Scheduled Reminder or CiviCRules but would depend on whether the tokens you need are available.

Comment: ie, i am not assuming that all the info required is 'in' the Activity